# user lib jar precedence over oozie share lib in spark action

Tags: java, apache-spark, jvm, classloader, oozie

Is below option a best approach to give user jar precedence over oozie share lib jar while running on yarn cluster (to resolve class conflict issue)?

```
<property>
    <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.user.classpath.first</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

For more details, [Apache Oozie ebook](https://books.google.com/books?id=9wU_CQAAQBAJ&pg=PT196&lpg=PT196&dq=oozie+launcher+options+user.classpath&source=bl&ots=jYhhd0vqy3&sig=RooGo8iWtVg-t7nFSkVsYJa1U_U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBvuqnwprZAhWMo1kKHbjsBTQQ6AEIcjAI#v=onepage&q=oozie%20launcher%20options%20user.classpath&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use this option but sometimes will get unexpected error while running the jobs if jars version is not compatible with yarn/spark cluster library (for example some methods might be removed in latest version).

Comment: In cluster there is class conflict in CDH jars. One hive jar have old version of common lang 3 class. To resolve that issue I was trying to find alternate approach.Any other suggestion to resolve class conflict in CDH jars in Spark action.

Comment: I had the same issue and I replaced common lang3 jars in spark share-lib with latest version.

Comment: but my scenario is little different. Share lib already have updated version of lang3 but hiveexec is a uber jar and it has old version of lang3. so sometimes job pics lang3 from hiveexec and it failes with nomethodfound error.